# laravel user's password is shown in array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this situation where I just happened to die and dump `dd($event)` an event where I injected the current `$user`.

I notice that, in the attributes part, I do see the password is shown in that collection. I have indeed added the `password` column inside the `$hidden` array.

Why is this happening. Is there something else I should do to keep it hidden?

I have tested by `dd($user)` the `$user` only.

Comment: `dd` is literally dumping the object, it has nothing to do with the serialization. `$model->toArray()/toJson()` is where serialization comes in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `dd` you will get exactly what you have in your database.

```
$user = \App\Models\User::find(1);
dd($user);
```

[image]

`hidden` fields works with `toJson` and `toArray` methods

```
$user = \App\Models\User::find(1);

dd($user->toArray());
```

[image]

Comment: Ahhhh... okkei ☺